# Dependency injection using PRISM Xamarin Forms doesn't work

Tags: xamarin.forms, dependency-injection, prism

I have a problem with dependency injection in my project. I use PRISM framework in my project and I chose Ioc container when create it. Link -> https://github.com/blackpantific/InstagroomEX
In my app.xaml file I associate the class and interface

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation();
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<WelcomeView, WelcomeViewModel>();
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<RegistrationView, RegistrationViewModel>();
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<LoginView, LoginViewModel>();

//regestering
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IValidationService, ValidationService>();
    }
```

But my page after initializing() doesn't appear at the screen. This is ViewModel constructor

```
public RegistrationViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IUserDataService userDataService,
IValidationService validationService) :
base(navigationService)
{
_userDataService = userDataService;
_validationService = validationService;
}
```

Something wrong here. When I pass to the RegistrationViewModel() constructor another parameters besides INavigationService navigationService the RegistrationView page doesn't not displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't register IUserDataService so PRISM can't find a matching constructor.

Comment: From what I can see from your code, the first page to be displayed shall be `WelcomePage` is that correct? Is `WelcomePage` displayed correctly?

Comment: Ireally didn't register another service in Android project. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `WelcomePage` is displayed correctly and `RegistrationPage` is not, I think that Andres Castro is correct: Prism tries to resolve the `IUserDataService` which is not possible. In the debug output you should see a message that `IUserDataService` cannot be resolved.

(**Note:** The following is based on my experiences with Prism and Unity. This might hold for other Dependency Injection frameworks, but it's possible that other frameworks behave differently.)

*Prism* relies on a Dependency Injection (*DI*) framework, for example Microsofts *Unity* application block. What happens when you try to navigate to `RegistrationPage` is, that Prism (**if** you are using `ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"`) tries to determine the type of the viewmodel (by convention) and asks the underlying DI framework to resolve this type (i.e. create an instance). For each of the required constructors parameters of this type, then again the DI framework tries to resolve them. If the parameters require concrete types it will then try to resolve those. If the parametery require interface (or abstract) types, the DI framework will look at its registrations and if the types have been registered create instances according to this registrations (which in turn might involve resolving other types).

**If - however - the parameter requires an interface type which has not been registered, the DI framework does not know how to handle the situation.** It coulld of course assume `null`, but this might lead to errors that might be way harder to track down, hence it will throw an exception (which is swallowed and Logged by Prism).

#### Now how can you handle the situation?

You'll need to tell the DI framework how to resolve `IUserDataInterface`. Since `RegistrationPageViewModel` does not actually use it, you could register `null`

```cs
containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IValidationService>(null);
```

Could be irritating later, though. I'd rather remove the dependency of `RegistrationPageViewModel` to `IUserDataService` altogether - for now and add it later when it's actually used - or create a mock/stub that implements `IUserDataService` and is used as long there is no real implementation. This would be registered with the DI framework as you did with `IValidationService`.